# "abundant in" vs "abundant with"

Tags: differences, idioms

I am curious as to whether *abundant in* is a more correct usage than *abundant with*?

For example, the sentence: "The mail room is abundant in letters" seems to have the same meaning when compared to "the mail room is abundant with letters"

I did some search, and it seems like [this source](https://lingohelp.me/preposition-after-adjective/abundant-in-with-of-on-for/) suggests that *abundant in* is used more often; however, no one seemed to disprove the usage of *abundant with*, either.

Is one of them the preferred usage in some scenario, or are they both correct in general?

Comment: Your example sentence is something no native English speaker would ever say.

Comment: I can't see this without thinking of Shrek describing the swamp..."... It's in an... enchanted forest, **abundant in squirrels**, and cute little duckies."

Answer (score 2):

Your example is a bit weird, but both prepositions are correct. See the following examples from well-respected dictionaries (my boldface):

> 2 b : amply supplied: ABOUNDING
>   // **an area *abundant* with bird life**
>   [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abundant)
>
> **2.** Having an abundance of something; abounding: ***a region abundant in wildlife.***
>   [American Heritage Dictionary (via FreeDictionary)](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/abundant)

Now the [website you looked at](https://lingohelp.me/preposition-after-adjective/abundant-in-with-of-on-for/) does say that *abundant in* is a lot more common than *abundant with*. But note that all the examples of *abundant in* there are of the type “lions are abundant in the crater”, and what you’re interested in are things like *the crater is abundant in lions* versus *the crater is abundant with lions*.

But if you look at this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abundant%20in%20wildlife%2Cabundant%20with%20wildlife&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cabundant%20in%20wildlife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabundant%20with%20wildlife%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cabundant%20in%20wildlife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabundant%20with%20wildlife%3B%2Cc0) you’ll see that, for instance, *abundant with wildlife* is more common than *abundant in wildlife*; whereas [this other Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=area%20abundant%20in%2Carea%20abundant%20with%2Cabundant%20in%20the%20area&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carea%20abundant%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carea%20abundant%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabundant%20in%20the%20area%3B%2Cc0) shows than *area abundant in* and *area abundant with* are about as common of late, and both are a lot less common than *abundant in the area*, which explains the results in your website.

Answer (score -1):

One potential answer is why should we seek to simplify language, and a second is why should we consider any string of words a phrase?

Consider:

> Use abundant in a sentence
>
> Use abundant with other other words like...

Which leaves us with the question: '...abundant in/with letters', where the choice of preposition may either be the author's preference or an attempt by the author to build a specific image for us.